# No such provider for https after Spring context upgrade

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I am working on Spring MVC application, which is sending email using Spring JavaMail package.i.e.

```
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl
```

I have the properties during bean creation

```
<bean id="mailInfo" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="port" value="25" />
        <!-- <property name="username" value="xxxx@yyy.com" /> -->
        <property name="username" value="aaaa@bbbb.com" />
        <property name="password" value="xxxxx" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">https</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.host">hostname</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">25</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.enable">false</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

It was working fine. I am adding the caching functionality using Ehcache 2.8.1. I had to upgrade the spring-context to atleast 3.1 version. But, when I upgraded the spring-context-support to 3.2.3. It started to throw the exception below.

```
ERROR MailServiceImpl:130 - MailSendException:Mail server connection failed; nested    
exception is javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for https.
Failed messages: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for https
```

I have been working on this issue for more than a day. Can someone please help me understand the problem? I am assuming that this would be a classpath issue. But, how can i solve this kind of issues. Please help.

Comment: The transport should probably be "smtp" not "https" (I mean on port 25..)

Comment: Thank you, RC. I just changed it to smtp. It just worked. You are my life saver. I am curious to know that the same configuration just worked before upgrade. How is that happening? Do you know about it.Please post a one liner answer. I will accept it. Thanks, Have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transport should probably be "smtp" not "https" (I mean on port 25..)

As far as I know, there's no "https" mail transport provider, maybe the java mail API used before and after upgrade is not the same and the old one did a fallback to "smtp".

See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/package-summary.html

Comment: I completely understand now. Thanks. - 'Fallback' logic has been doing the stuff in the right way before..